# How do you change the current web address's subdomain using a tampermonkey script?

Tags: subdomain, tampermonkey

I am currently trying to create a simple tampermonkey script to change the web address's sub domain if it is not a certain subdomain using a variable. How would you do this? I am new to programming and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Auto-WikiLang (AWL)
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.2
// @description  Automatically change wikipedia's language to your language.
// @author       Jack Gaynor
// @match        https://*.wikipedia.org/*
// @exclude      https://en.wikipedia.org/*
// Change the above to fit your language
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

location.hostname = "en.wikipedia.org"; // change the subdomain to your language
```

I found it out